# Instantly assign static IP address in embedded Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, embedded-linux

Is there some basic Linux way to assign a static IP address without writing some files, just for the current session until reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do that with `ifconfig` tool. Most `Linux`-based systems come with `ifconfig` by default. Usage:

```
ifconfig <interface> <IP>
```

Example:

```
 ifconfig eth0 192.168.100.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: `ifconfig` has been superseded by `ip`. `ip` has more functionality, a cleaner syntax, and it's easier to parse the output in scripts.

Assuming you want to add a `/24` address on `eth0`, use:

```
ip addr add 192.168.100.100/24 dev eth0
```

Just

```
ip addr
```

will show the assigned addresses for all interfaces.